# Microsoft SSIS Designer ver 16.0 not able to connect to MySQL when running a data flow

Tags: mysql, ssis, odbc

I try to develop SSIS ETL with MySQL as both the OLTP source and OLAP target. My DEV environment has Visual Studio 2019 + SSIS/SSDT ver 16.0 and MySQL 32bit ODBC driver 5.3 (64bit won't work for the SSIS version, and driver 8.x doesn't seem to have 32bit). I create "user DSN" to my ETL source and target -- "system DSN" won't work for SSIS.

I was able to create ODBC connection managers.

I was able to drag-n-drop ODBC source and target on a data flow.

For the ODBC source, I was able to use Table Name to view the table columns but got error when preview the data. So I use SQL with the MySQL syntax. Then I was able to preview the data.

For the ODBC target, I was able to see the columns and map the column.

But when I "Debug --> Start" or run the data flow without debugging in the VS SSIS designer, I got:

Error: 0xC0014009 at Sure BI: There was an error trying to establish an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) connection with the database server.
Error: 0xC020801C at Claim Party, Get catastrophe [2]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "SCE_QA_32BIT_USR" failed with error code 0xC0014009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues helped find the root cause and a solution.

Root Cause: Visual Studio 2019 is 32bit IDE and therefore everything that runs in the debugger should be 32bit. However, VS by default tries to make ODBC connection by 64bit drivers.

Solution: Choose menu option Debug --> Debug Properties.
[image]

Set Debugging --> Run64bitRuntime to False
[image]